# Run time Error 1004 --------Group Method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have used below mentioned VBA CODE and getting an error here:

`Selection.Columns.Group`

```
Sub Macro()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb0 As Workbook


ThisWorkbook.Activate
cmnth = Sheet1.Range("AQ1").Value
pmnth = Sheet1.Range("AR1").Value
pmnthf = Sheet1.Range("AS1").Value

cfile = Sheet1.Range("C1").Value & "\TB_Trust-CC_" & cmnth & ".xlsx "

pfile = Sheet1.Range("C2").Value & "\TB_Trust-CC_" & pmnth & ".xlsx "


Set wb0 = Workbooks.Open(pfile)
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(cfile)

wb.Activate




For i = 4 To 12

cc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("C" & i).Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cc).Activate

Columns("E:AR").Select
Selection.Columns.Group
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Columns("H:AN").Copy
Range("AT1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: @arcadeprecinct I'm presuming that you meant to say 'you **shouldn't** us `Activate` and `Select` :)

Comment: @Zac Oh my god of course. Too late to edit...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. Is the sheet in question formatted in any way? Btw, you should**N'T** use Activate and Select. Just use direct references like `wb.Sheets(cc).Columns("E:AR").Group`